# Given a set of $(x,y)$ coordinate pairs how can I come up with the equation for a curve?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Say for example I have a set of coordinate pairs as follows:

```
x     y
0     100
20    90
100   0
```

I would like to generate an equation for this curve In the following format:

$$y = ax^2 + bx + c$$

Based on the example data the result that I obtained from Excel is:

$$y = -0.0063x^2 - 0.375x + 100$$

So, my question is, how would I be able to come up with $a, b, c$ on my own if I had to do it by hand.  I need this for a program I am writing in c#, but I'm just not sure where to begin with the math.

Comment: You need a quadratic fit function; this can be done a couple of different ways, but resources should be plenty on the interwebs!

Comment: It's called quadratic curve fitting, you should find something on the web for it.

Comment: Put the three points into the equation and solve the three simultaneous linear equations for $a$, $b$ and $c$. Careful - there will be cases with no solution, or more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the general form for a parabola and "plug in" the correct values in order to obtain the coefficients. Like so:

$$ax^2+bx+c=y$$

But we have three different equations:

$$100=a(0)^2+b(0)+c$$
$$90=a(20)^2+b(20)+c$$
$$0=a(100)^2+b(100)+c$$

Well, it immediately follows that $c=100$, so we can alter our equations:

$$90=a(20)^2+b(20)+100$$
$$0=a(100)^2+b(100)+100$$

Here, subtract $100$ from both equations and solve as you would any system of 2 linear equations.

My recommendation is to multiply the second equation by $(-1/5)$ and add it to the first.

**Edit**

So, hopefully you will agree that

$$0=a(100)^2+b(100)+100$$
and 
$$-\frac{1}{5} [0=a(100)^2+b(100)+100]$$

are the same equation. But then

$$-\frac{1}{5} [0=a(100)^2+b(100)+100]$$
is the same as
$$0=-a\frac{(100)^2}{5}-b(20)-20]$$

You now take the 1st equation and add it to the second (some people call this solving a system of equations *by elimination*:

$$0=-a\frac{(100)^2}{5}-b(20)-20]$$
$$+[90=a(20)^2+b(20)+100]$$

from this we can obtain the final equation only in terms of $a$:

$$90=-a\frac{(100)^2}{5}+a(20)^2+80$$

from here, it is trivial to solve for $a$, and the by substitution obtain the value for $b$.

I hope that was clearer.

Comment: I followed through your steps and was able to replicate the results in my original example like you said by solving for a or b and substituting the variables back into the original equations.  Thank you for the great explanation it was easy to follow even for a not so math-savy person like myself.  However, I'm confused about your recommendation of multiplying by (-1/5).  I don't see where this is coming from or how it applies.  I went ahead and accepted the answer since I was able to solve it but if you don't mind, can you explain the last part?

Comment: Absolutely: I will add an explanation in my answer. Congratulations on finishing the problem

Comment: I tried to add some explanation, but believe me, it is actually a very short process to obtain results and often times quicker than substitution if you're clever.

Comment: Very nice! So you chose (-1/5) because of the relationship between 100 & 20.  This all makes sense now.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, for precisely that reason. In general, you pick a scalar to multiple one of the equations by in order to "cancel" one of the variables.